# Why this drupal form not working?

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

Drupal 7, the $output is showing string "Array" on my page, i don't know why, this is the code:

Its working only this way: `return drupal_get_form('test_exp_form')`

But i need to add html, and text to my $output variable and i can't just return the form.

```
function test_page() {
     $output = '<div>Hello</div>';
     $output = drupal_get_form('test_exp_form');
     return $output;
}

function test_exp_form($form, &$form_stat) {
  $form = array();

    $form['example_textfield'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Example Textfield'),
      '#default_value' => 'some text',
    );

  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`render()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/render/7) function in Drupal 7 as `drupal_get_form` returns a 'render array':

```
function test_page() {
  $output = '<div>Hello</div>';
  $output .= render(drupal_get_form('test_exp_form'));
  return $output;
}
```

Here's some more info about render arrays in Drupal 7:

[Render arrays in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/930760)

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer, I've just tested this and it works